# What do indexed mean in 'indexed family' in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What do indexed mean in 'indexed family' in set theory?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please edit your question so it doesn't use about a million levels of nested blockquotes.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/what-is-the-difference-between-family-and-set.

Comment: Indeed, the accepted answer to the question referenced by @lhf above is the right answer.

Comment: But then what is index set

Comment: The index set can be any set. When you view the indexed family as a function, the index set is the domain of the function.

Comment: goodbye! :) :) :)