# What distinguishes 'family' vs. 'set' of functions?

Tags: functions

Source: Stewart, James. [*Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (6 edn 2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495011665).

> [p. 50 Top:]   To understand how the expression for a function relates to its graph, it’s helpful to graph
>   **a family of functions**, that is, a collection of functions whose equations are related. In the
>   next example we graph members of a family of cubic polynomials.
>
> [p. 391 Middle:]   You should distinguish carefully between definite and indefinite integrals. A definite
>   integral $\int^b_a f(x) \,dx$ is a number, whereas an indefinite integral $\int f(x) \,dx$ is a *function* (or
>   ***family [format mine]*** of functions).

1. Of functions: how does 'family' differ from 'set'?
2. Why did James Stewart write 'family' instead of 'set'?

I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35462/53259) that feels too advanced for univariate calculus.

Comment: I have heard it in the context of "the exponential family of functions" which can be written $f(x)\exp[g(x)]$ for some functions $\cases{f: x\to f(x)\\ g: x\to g(x)}$. A set of functions are not necessarily related by a common expression like that.

Comment: I guess to suggest some common feature.  A set could be a totally random bunch of stuff.

Comment: The same as @badjohn.

Comment: "Family" does not have a precise definition here.  But the usage does often imply that the functions in the given family have some properties in common.

Comment: The question is answered pretty well in the post you linked. The answer isn't "advanced". If it is unclear to you, you might want to ask for details.

Comment: I much prefer Calculus by Spivak to Stewart's text.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a definition that might work (though it looks like the author's definition is more general and much fuzzier).

A family is a set that is related in a known way by parameters.  Let's look at some examples.

Consider the equation for a line:  $f(x)=mx+b$; here $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the "y-intercept".  Consider the case where $m$ is $1$ and $b$ is 0.  If we graph it, we get a line at 45 degrees.  What if $m=0$ and $b=0$?  Then we get a horizontal line (that lies on the x axis).  So you see that we get different lines by changing the slope and y-intercept.  We can call these lines a family of lines; they're related by the parameters $m$ and $b$.

How about an indefinite integral?  Suppose $f$ is the indefinite integral of $f'$.  Then one indefinite integral of $f'$ is $f+1$.  And another indefinite integral is $f+2$.  And yet another is $f+0$.  So you see that a general expression of the families of indefinite integrals is $f+c$.  And that's the family of functions related by the parameter $c$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a definition of family in "Dictionnaire des Mathématiques Modernes" of Larousse.

Let $S$ and $I$ be two sets. An injection of $I$ into $S$ is called a **family of elements of $S$ indexed by $I$** and it is noted $i\to x_i$ or $\{x_i\}_ {i \in I}$.
The set $I$ is called then **set of indices**.

Every subset $P$ of $S$ can be considered as a family of elements of S, thanks to the canonical injection of $P$ in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression *a set of functions* means a collection of functions, grouped together by some basic common property. For example,
$$
L^2[0,1] = \left\{ f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \left| \int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx < \infty\right.\right\}.
$$
The relationship feature is common for all functions in the class, but not strong enough to call it a family.

A *family of functions* typically suggest a very strong relationship, in structure, or in form, perhaps differing by values of a couple of parameters. For example, a set of solutions to $y'(t) = y(t)$ is a family of functions $$y(t) = Ce^t,$$
a much stronger relationship than the one above.

---

Your example from Stewart is a classic form of this usage. The expression $\int f(x) dx$ represents a family of functions $\mathcal{F} = \{F(x) + c\}$, different by the constant factor $c$ only, having the property that if $\phi \in \mathcal{F}$ then $\phi'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  A set of objects does not need to be related.  For example, the set {camel, f(x)=2x+3, Donald Trump} is a set.  Similarly, you can have a set of functions that aren't related in any obvious way.  For example, {f(x)=2x+3, f(x)=sin(x), f(x)=1 if x is rational and x^2 if x is irrational}.  This is, indeed, a set of functions.  However, it's not a family of functions (it's not a set of functions related in a simple way).

Comment: @NicNic8 just a phrasing error -- common property needed to distinguish the functions in the set, not that it is intrinsically necessary

Answer (score 0):

Given a ground set $X$ of "animals" (objects of type "animal") a *set of animals* is a subset $A$  of $X$. The elements of $A$ are neither ordered, nor numbered, nor is there any other "organizing" structure implied on $A$. Any "animal" $x\in X$ is either an element of $A$, or not. Basta.

Now families. Given an arbitrary "index set" $I$, a function $$f:\quad I\mapsto X\qquad \iota\mapsto x_\iota$$
names for each $\iota\in I$ a certain animal $x_\iota \in X$, whereby the same animal can be named several times. If we are not interested in the abstract triple $(I,X,f)$ per se, nor on some extraneous properties of $f$, like continuity, etc., but only on the *list* (or *array*) of animals produced (or organized)  by $I$ and $f$, then we denote this list by $(x_\iota)_{\iota\in I}$, and call it a *family of animals*.

A definite integral $\int_a^b f(x)\>dx$ is a number. An indefinite integral $\int f(x)\>dx$ is a **set** of functions, namely the set of all functions $F$ satisfying $F'=f$ (on some agreed interval). But $\int f(x)\>dx$ is **not a family** of functions, whereas
$\bigl(x^3+C\bigr)_{C\in{\mathbb R}}$ is. Think about it!